# Finding a specific value in a datatable row

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am trying to search a datatable for a specific value, which is based on an ID. In sql it would be something like:

```
Select FIlepath Where ID = 'x'
```

but so far I have had no luck, I have tried a few methods including passing the entire row into an array and selecting the value from the array but nothing has worked so far.

However I just found the .Where function for searching a datatable and thought this might be the quickest, cleanest way to do things. But it requires a predicate.

The below code is what I have for this at the moment but I think the problem is with the "ofString" part of the code.

```
objDataTable_FailCodeDetails.Select(("FilePath")).Where(Of String("ID ='" & i - 1 & "'"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

cheers.

Comment: Use a dataview, much easier and cleaner. It also has filters that can be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTable object has a simple and straightforward method to extract DataRows that satisfy a WHERE condition

```
 DataRows[] rows = objDataTable_FailCodeDetails.Select("ID ='" & i - 1 & "'")
```

This assumes that the ID field is a text field, so you need the single quotes around the i value, but if it is a simple integer then you write

```
 DataRows[] rows = objDataTable_FailCodeDetails.Select("ID =" & i - 1)
```

Instead if you want to use a Linq expression it would be

```
 Dim result = objDataTable_FailCodeDetails.AsEnumerable() _ 
                          .Where(Function(x) _
                             x.Field(Of String)("ID")  =  (i - 1).ToString())
```